# After calling projectRaster in R, missing right edge of world map when plotting with ggplot

Tags: r

I'm using `projectRaster` and `rasterToPoints` in R to get a dataframe with lat/lon coordinates for plotting in `ggplot` but I seem to be losing the right edge of the map (New Zealand). I'm not sure if this is an issue with my use of `projectRaster` or `rasterToPoints` or `geom_raster`

Here's my initial rasterLayer:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 1  (of  4  bands)
dimensions  : 578, 943, 545054  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 46261.72, 46261.72  (x, y)
extent      : -20134202, 23490599, -9583413, 17155861  (xmin, xmax, ymin, 
ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 
+x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
```

Which produces:
[image]

And here's my code to to project and convert to a dataframe:

```
wgs84 <- "+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
+towgs84=0,0,0"
b.wgs <- projectRaster(dilmap, crs=CRS(wgs84))
b2.wgs <- rasterToPoints(b.wgs, spatial=TRUE)
b2.df <- as.data.frame(b2.wgs)

plot(b.wgs)
```

[image]

EDIT: Added plot of b.wgs

Comment: Does plotting `b.wgs` look correct? Also, if I try your code with a `dilmap` created from random data with the same size/extent etc as your but with random numbers I get "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (362406): x, y, fill" which might actually be a clue. Is the nrows(b2.df) the same as the number of cells in `dilmap`? Because I think they have to match to make this work. In any case, I'd use `tmap` package for plotting spatial and avoid `ggplot`.

Comment: Aha, `b.wgs` is indeed clipped. nrows of 430 in `b.wgs` but 578 in `dilmap`. Any idea how I correct?

Comment: Even using a reference raster to align nrow, ncol and ncell still not solving the problem of the right edge not plotting.
`dimensions  : 578, 943, 545054  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.3817603, 0.3114187  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : dilmap 
values      : 0, 253.858  (min, max)`

Comment: Can you edit your Q and show what `b.wgs` looks like? If it is clipped then all the stuff about making a data frame and using ggplot isn't relevant.

Comment: Yep, looks like that's the issue. Is there an easy way to correct for the stretching and clipping? Do I need to edit the CRS defined in `wgs84` or add an argument to `projectRaster()`? Sorry for the ignorance, clearly I'm a GIS newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Your source raster isn't from -180 to +180 in its coordinate system - it goes beyond +180 and this is being chopped when you transform it. To see:

Create a point at almost +180E on the equator:

```
> pt = SpatialPoints(coords=matrix(c(179.9,0),ncol=2),proj4string=CRS(wgs84))
```

Now transform to the coordinate system of your raster to see where it would be:

```
> coordinates(spTransform(pt, CRS(projection(dilmap))))
     coords.x1     coords.x2
[1,]  20026376 -7.081155e-10
```

But your raster extent has an x-coordinate max of:

```
> xmax(dilmap)
[1] 23490599
```

which is a lot bigger than the X coord of the transformed point. So the right hand portion of your raster is beyond +180E. When transforming the coordinates this actually gets wrapped round to the western hemisphere, and will overlap with the portion of raster on the left of your image, because the left edge of your raster *is* at 180W, or near enough:

```
> pt = SpatialPoints(coords=matrix(c(-179.9,0),ncol=2),proj4string=CRS(wgs84))
> coordinates(spTransform(pt, CRS(projection(dilmap))))
     coords.x1     coords.x2
[1,] -20026376 -7.081155e-10
> xmin(dilmap)
[1] -20134202
```

So there's something fundamentally wrong with your source raster, and you should check carefully you've got the CRS correct or that the data hasn't been manipulated or shifted or otherwise mashed up, or that its extent hasn't been set wrongly.